# Swift 3 Error in time interval between two dates

Tags: datetime, swift3

I am trying to determine the interval between two dates that I create using DateComponents. If I make the first date 1 year prior to the second, I get 365 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds. If I make the dates further apart (400 years here), suddenly my date is off by 11 minutes 56 seconds. Here is the code:

```
import Foundation
var mycal = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
var datum = DateComponents(year:1600, month:1, day:1, hour:12, minute:0,
                           second:0)
let j2000 = DateComponents(year:2000, month:1, day:1, hour:12, minute:0,
                           second:0)
let datum_date = mycal.date(from: datum)
let j2000_date = mycal.date(from: j2000)

let interval = mycal.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from:j2000_date!, to:datum_date!)
print("Datum: \(datum_date!)") //1600-01-01 19:48:04 +0000
print("j2000: \(j2000_date!)") //2000-01-01 20:00:00 +0000
```

Note the next-to-last line: Comments show what the print produces. I've tried it with the Gregorian calendar too, same problem. I'm not sure exactly how far back the inconsistency occurs, I've gone back far enough to produce and it sometimes seems to "stick" as I change the code moving closer in time again. Strangely, the "interval" appears to show the correct amount of days(here -146097), but the date shown is incorrect and I will likely need that in my calculations. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There is no error.

Comment: There is no error in "interval", but why is the date produced off by 11:56? I edited my first paragraph; I mistakenly said my interval was off, but it is actually the produced date. Thanks.

Comment: Calendar adjustments. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar Why would you need that?

Comment: The Gregorian calendar was introduced in 1582 and many countries adopted it after 1600. This could be the reason.

Comment: Is there a calendar adjustment that would produce a difference of only about 12 minutes? As to why: I am trying to get a "Julian Day", the start point for most astronomical calculations with the user inputting via a DatePicker.

Comment: There is no error. Just use date formatter and get the string representation from your date `"January 1, 1913 at 12:00:00 PM GMT-3:06:28"`

Comment: Thanks Vadian ... I am aware of how the Julian/Gregorian calendar change took place. The date error occurs with a difference of only 100 years (i.e., if I change 'datum' to year 1900). I am assuming a proleptic Gregorian Calendar for the calculations; this seems a valid assumption since the 'interval' is correct all the way to year -4712, the earliest year I need.

Comment: As I said your date it is correct for your timezone try `let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateStyle = .long
df.timeStyle = .long
df.string(from: datum_date!)`

Comment: Thanks Leo, I will give that a try. Still scratching my head though ...

Comment: By the way ... I actually wrote swift code to implement a Julian Day calcuation (my first swift code!) using Jean Meeus's "Astronomical Algorithms". It worked perfectly on it's own ... but when using a DatePicker, produced a Julian date for 'far back' dates (100 years or more, for example) that was off by ... 11:56! That's why I'm going for the 'interval' method now.

Comment: Thanks for the input, everyone, but exactly WHY this occurs will probably remain a mystery to me. As Leo Dabus implied (I think), if I use DateFormatter() to extract a string, then use DateFormatter() again to produce a date, the DateComponents() are correct for use in calculations. It seems a rather inelegant work-around; kinda like taking a picture of something, then painting it, then taking a picture of the painting to show everyone. But I've seen admonishments on StackOverflow to use DateFormatter() instead of manipulating actual date objects ... so I will!

Answer (score 0):

The difference could be related to leep year adjustments but that would give a difference of 11 minutes and 14 seconds (there'd still be 40 seconds unaccounted for, 26 of which could be leep seconds).

see: https://www.infoplease.com/leap-year-101-next-when-list-days-calendar-years-calculation-last-rules

In Theory, if you compute a multi-year time difference with a precision of minutes and seconds, you should get variations of 5 hours 48 minutes and 46 seconds every 3 out of four years and get within 11 minutes and 14 seconds on the fourth year.  I don't know how macOS (Unix) deals with that there there is probably a bunch of considerations that they need to take into account (especially beyond 400 year where that 11 minutes 14 seconds gets adjusted).

If that level of precision is required by your use case, I would suggest reading up on the minute details of time calculations.  Given that dates are stored internally as a number of seconds, going back to a precise day and time over these long periods must require some special math acrobatics.

See Apple's documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendar

Comment: Thanks Alain, but really this does not account for the difference. And this difference persists across a wide range of 'far back' dates. I did try DateFormatter() to pull out the date as a string (which actually has the correct time) and again to convert it to a date (as Leo Dabus hinted at). This doesn't explain why printing the Date object directly is incorrect but it does allow me to use the values in a calculation.